# Javascript not working on Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

My code has

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

up at the top and when I upload my code using dreamweaver my website works perfectly fine in Google Chrome, but anything regarding Javascript does not work once I'm in live mode for dreamweaver. I made sure to check that freezze javascript was off as well.
Not sure what's wrong =/

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure, but I think dreamweaver requires the src to start with 'http://' and not only '//' if it needs to use files from online.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to internet i.e. the scripts get downloaded in live mode? #JustSaying

Comment: @w3shivers It worked! Wanna make a post so I can pick you as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver requires a full http path to be used so change the source to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As shown in the example above I simply added http: in the src tag.